# Elements of spectral theory - functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I define: The operator $R( \lambda ; T)=(\lambda I-T)^{-1}$.
According to the chapter on elements of spectral theory, I must demonstrate the following:

$$\rho(T)=\rho(T^*)\quad\text{and}\quad R(\lambda;T^*)= R(\lambda;T)^*$$

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you're allowed to use to prove the claim.  First of all, the spectral radius $\rho(T)$ is

$$
\rho(T) \;\; =\;\; \sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(T)} |\lambda|.
$$

You can immediately see this if you know that $\sigma(T^*) = \overline{\sigma(T)}$, in other words the spectra of $T$ and $T^*$ are conjugate to one another.

As for your other claim, I believe you're stating the result incorrectly.  The result should really be
$$
R\left (\lambda, T^*\right ) \;\; =\;\; R\left (\overline{\lambda}, T\right )^*.
$$

If you let $\varphi \in Dom(T)$ and $\psi \in Dom (T^*)$ you can see that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle R(\lambda, T^*)\varphi, \psi\rangle & = & \langle \varphi, (\lambda I - T^*)\psi\rangle \\
& = & \left \langle \varphi, \left (\overline{\lambda}I - T\right )^*\psi \right \rangle \\
& = & \left \langle \left (\overline{\lambda}I - T\right )\varphi, \psi \right \rangle \\
& = & \left \langle \varphi, R\left (\overline{\lambda}, T\right )\psi \right \rangle
& = & \left \langle  R\left (\overline{\lambda}, T\right )^*\varphi, \psi \right \rangle.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Rho(T) is not be espectral radius. The resolvent set Rho(T) of T consists of all complex number Lambda for which (lambda*I-T)^-1 is a bounded operator (with domain X). The spectrum sigma(T) of T consists of the complement of Rho(T) in C(complex)

Comment: @KariBuckRomán Ok, sorry about the confusion.  I've seen spectral radius denoted with $\rho$ in the texts I've used.  I'll try to amend my answer when I have some time today.